# Why my Mask Rcnn predict everything for one class

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, object-detection

everyone
I run my test codes of Mask Rcnn, it only predcit everything is "cat", however, I have two classes cat and dog except background. I use VIA to annotate the mask images. I only annotate 70 images totally. I am not sure the problem is from my codes or insufficient annotated images. The test codes are shown below.

```
    import os
import mrcnn.visualize
import cv2
import time
from mrcnn.config import Config
from datetime import datetime
# Root directory of the project
ROOT_DIR = os.getcwd()
# Root directory of the project


# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_balloon_0030.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
# Directory of images to run detection on
IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "images2")



class_names = ['BG', 'cat', 'dog']
class SimpleConfig(mrcnn.config.Config):
    NAME = "coco_inference"
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1
    NUM_CLASSES = len(class_names)

import mrcnn.model

# Create model object in inference mode.
model = mrcnn.model.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=ROOT_DIR, config=SimpleConfig())

model.load_weights(filepath=COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)

class_names = ['BG', 'cat', 'dog']
# Load a random image from the images folder
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Mask_RCNN-2.1\images2\test3.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

r = model.detect([image], verbose=1)

r = r[0]

mrcnn.visualize.display_instances(image=image,
                                  boxes=r['rois'],
                                  masks=r['masks'],
                                  class_ids=r['class_ids'],
                                  class_names=class_names,
                                  scores=r['scores'])
```

Thank you very much! Hope for help!

[The wrong predcit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ASgm.png)